# String as foreign key reference SQL - support i18l for preset data tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have an answer to my question even before posting it but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. Here's the business problem:

To support i18l of fixed data tables. The application is fully locale aware but some of the text that is displayed on pages comes from the database. Here's an example:

Table is 'period':

```
INSERT INTO PERIOD (lang, ref, desc) VALUES
('en', 'HOUR', 'Hourly'),
('en', 'WEEK', 'Weekly'),
('en', 'MONTH', 'Monthly'),
('de', 'HOUR', 'Stündlich'),
('de', 'WEEK', 'Wöchentlich'),
('de', 'MONTH', 'Monatlich');
```

The reason I'm not using the auto generated ID is because when someone is using the site in German, and select 'Wochentlich' for a weekly occurrence, we want, if the locale is changed to English, we want 'Weekly' to be displayed. If we were using ID then that would be fixed to the actual selected item and we'd end up with sentences like 'this client has a wochtenlich standing order' - a bit dumb as you can see.  So we've resolved it by storing the 'ref' as the 'foreign key' instead.  Each query to obtain such data uses the 'ref' and a 'lang' parameter to obtain the correct item in the currently set language.

I know the disadvantages, that we don't get the correct relationship in the database as we cannot specify the VARCHAR as a foreign key.  (We're using MySQL 5.x)

Can anyone suggest a more correct way of resolving this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by not being able to ref because there is no auto-generated id. You *can* reference VARCHAR columns as foreign keys, you just need to specify them as corresponding primary keys in the referenced table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would design the app to store one row for each period type, and use additional columns for each of the translated terms.

```
INSERT INTO PERIOD (ref, desc_en, desc_de) VALUES
('HOUR', 'Hourly', 'Stündlich'),
('WEEK', 'Weekly', 'Wöchentlich'),
('MONTH', 'Monthly', 'Monatlich');
```

You can get a list of all period descriptions for a given locale:

```
SELECT desc_de FROM PERIOD;
```

You can get a description in a given locale for a given period:

```
SELECT desc_de FROM PERIOD WHERE ref = 'WEEK';
```

You can even account for cases when you don't have the translation done:

```
SELECT COALESCE(desc_de, desc_en) AS desc FROM PERIOD WHERE ref = 'WEEK';
```

You can get a description from a user-specified locale (be careful to whitelist the locale choice, to avoid SQL injection).  For example in PHP:

```
$locales = array('en'=>1, 'de'=>1);
$locale = array_key_exists($_GET['locale'], $locales) ? $_GET['locale'] : 'en';
$sql = "SELECT desc_{$locale} FROM PERIOD WHERE ref = 'WEEK'";
```

PS: For what it's worth, you *can* use a varchar as a primary key or foreign key in any version of MYSQL (as long as you use InnoDB).

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE BAR (foo_id VARCHAR(10), FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES FOO(id));
```

Comment: I think that's a great solution - that was the first that was implemented until we realised that this system will be deployed in many countries, each with a different set of localized data for these tables. e.g. (English will be an option for all countries)

Comment: but would be deployed in:
Germany: German and English
Switzerland: German, French, Italian, English
UK: English only
France: French and English
etc. etc.

So we didn't want to fill up, e.g. the UK website with data that is never used with languages from all the other deploys - then if we get a new deploy in a language that is not yet supported, then we'd have to add columns etc. (I know, not a big deal but we considered it a messy solution given that there will be many deploys each with a different set of language options)

However, thank you for your proposal!

Comment: And I will investigate InnoDB to see if it can be easily plugged in - the system is complete except a few translations and images.

Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Everyone who uses a modern version of MySQL should treat InnoDB as the *default* storage engine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll have to research to see how to set our MySQL installation to InnoDB (and hope that cloudbees.com allow it also as that's where we're deploying) but in the meantime I'm marking your response as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You might like to read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html